# How to export full size smart object, but maintain layer properties

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, export

I am a developer not a designer, thus am not particularly familiar with photoshop, and may subsequently get some of my terms incorrect.

I have a PSD that contains several layers outlining the design of a website. One of the layers is a cropped jpeg. The jpeg has also had some filters added to it...

I would like to export this layer, however, I need it in as high resolution as possible. I **do not** want it the same size as the layer appears in my psd, I need it the same size as it appear when I double click on it, whilst also maintaining the filters and croppings...

Is this possible or do I have to export the full size image and then apply the filters and cropping myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy method to do this.

If the **Smart Object** has **Smart Filters** applied to it, that means you can **double-click the filter** item in the Layer Panel and see the settings.

[image: smart Filters]

Your best bet would be to **open the smart object** and copy/paste or **duplicate** its contents to a new document. Then go through the smart Filters **noting the settings for each filter** and **reapply** those filters to the **duplicated image**.